# Can you suggest me a module which allows to show user app's features in react-native?

Tags: react-native, demo

Is there someone who knows the module which allows to show the user the use of our application?
I knew it but i have not found it...!

Comment: what do you mean by `app's features`?

Comment: When the user launch for the first rime the app, i wanna give him a tutorial...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you need an introduction slider like something?

In that case, you can use `react-native-app-intro-slider`.

Check details in here

https://github.com/Jacse/react-native-app-intro-slider

**Edit**

In that case, you can use `react-native-copilot`

[Details](https://github.com/okgrow/react-native-copilot)

[Demo](https://expo.io/@mohebifar/copilot-example)

Comment: Not this...a tutorial after login which shows user how to use the app...

Comment: Thanks, that was what i was looking for

Answer (score 0):

there are different ways of implementation. One of them is using  `localStorage.setItem()` and `localStorage.getItem()`. for example, you can have a variable `showInstruction` and set its value to true. When the application starts, check the variable by `localStorage.getItem()` and if it is false, skip the `Modal`(instructions), if it is true, show the `Modal` to the user. remember at the end of instruction you should set `showInstruction` to false to stop showing modal every time you start the application by `localStorage.setItem()`.